# Excel: Get background color of cell using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I need to get RGB value of cell AU5 (which is filled with black color), but my function shows RGB value of G53. And I just don't know, how to pass the value of cell to function....

[image][image]

And here is a function in VBA:

[image]

Maybe anyone could help to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just wrap `indirect()` around your cell ref.  So, in G54, use `=getRGB(Indirect(G53))`.

Without `indirect()`, the `getRGB()` function looks to the cell you pointed to, in this case G53.  Since you want the formula to look to see what's in G53, and use *that* reference, just add `indirect()`.

Answer (score 2):

Making the function a little easier for myself - that might also help you:

```
Function getRGB(RefCell As String) As String

    Dim mystr As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range(RefCell & ":" & RefCell)
    Application.Volatile
    mystr = Right("000000" & Hex(rng.Interior.Color), 6)
    getRGB = Application.Hex2Dec(Right(mystr, 2)) & ", " & _
            Application.Hex2Dec(Mid(mystr, 3, 2)) & ", " & _
            Application.Hex2Dec(Left(mystr, 2))

End Function
```

In Excel, do this:

```
=getRGB("AU5")

' Result: 0, 0, 0
```